# Modify local variable from another script in Lua

Tags: lua, local

I'm trying to make a mod for the game Don't Starve Together, which makes use of Lua.  For this reason, **I can't modify their source variables/files**.

In order to try to modify the world generation, I need to access a local table that was instantiated in another file (the file is called "levels.lua").  The variable name is "levellist".  Is there a way to access the variable so that I can add certain elements to the table?

Namely, I want to add {"task_set", "cave_custom"} to levellist[DST_CAVE].overrides.

If someone could help or even just tell me if this is possible or not, that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the script for levels.lua:
http://pastebin.com/H54QRTi2

Comment: Here is the code where DST_CAVE is initialized: http://pastebin.com/qZDeXEe3.  I want to basically replace {"task_set", "cave_default"} with {"task_set", cave_custom"}.  I could just create a whole new level using AddLevel, but then I would need to find a way to have their code include that level in the previous one's stead.

Comment: With the provided sippets I cant see any good way of accessing either `levellist` or `levellist[DST_CAVE]`. You may need to use the replace method if possible. You can also look around more if either `levellist[DST_CAVE]` or `levellist` or `levellist[DST_CAVE].overrides` are exposed. One solution could be that you create a metatable for any of the accessible tables inside `levellist` and use a metamethod like `__index` to try access the `levellist` table through that.

Comment: Sorry what's the replace method?  Would this allow me to run my script in place of theirs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107186/discussion-between-rochet2-and-nathan-chan).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do simply **doesn't make sense**. Local variables are accessible only from the scope it was defined in, and it's nested scopes. There is no, normal, way to change it from different scopes, let alone an entirely different script.

If you want variables that all your scripts use, **use globals**.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't get to local variables (i.e. "pointers") used by another function, save for obscure debug methods that are rarely exposed to user sandbox, but you don't need to. Because you do not want to modify some local variable (i.e. make it point to another table for example), but get to some table and modify value inside it. So you just need to find any place where it is exposed to you in any way.

You should somehow edit in relevant content in your question because it is PITA to Alt-Tab back and forth to your files. According to structure from comments/chat `AddLevel(LEVELTYPE.SURVIVAL, ...)` inserts an entry into `levellist[LEVELTYPE.SURVIVAL]` table. If you check `levels.lua` you can also see that it returns table with `sandbox_levels` assigned exactly to this.

So:

```
local levels = require "levels"
print(levels.sandbox_levels)
-- Will print "table: SOMENUMBERS" - i.e. address of levellist[LEVELTYPE.SURVIVAL]
```

You now can iterate it with `for idx = 1, #levels.sandbox_levels` or `ipairs` and find entry belonging to `"DST_CAVE"`. I can't tell how field with ID will be called or how it will be structured because data is preprocessed with function `Level` before inserting that you did not include in the files you posted.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, this may not be your best strategy.

But depending on your environment, it may be *possible* to **abuse** some more esoteric features of the runtime to let you indirectly modify values that aren't "yours". Have a look at [debug.sethook](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.2.html) and [setfenv](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.3.html).

Comment: Caution: this will be hairy at best.